# Ajax Post to php setting parent directory as subdirectory

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am using ajax to post data to a php file and the code works fine

```
           $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/delete.php', 
            data: 'do=add', 
            success: function(responseText) {
            alert(responseText);

                alert('done');


                }
            });
```

This file is located in a folder called 'ajax' as in /ajax/index.php

The php file is

```
      <?php 
require_once('/check_fields.php');
           // more processing
      ?>
```

Located in /www/

The ajax was not functioning and i enabled error reporting and it said

```
 'No file such as /ajax/check_fields.php'
```

The ajax is setting the parent directory as the subdirectory of which im access the file of . as in the 'ajax' folder is being set as the default directory instead of /www/

i know i can use the ./../check_fields.php to resolve this problem but if i was including a lot of php files , the above is a tedious task.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated guys .

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably create a config file that gets loaded into any php file which defines absolute paths.

```
<?
//constants
  define( 'ROOT_PATH', '/www/ );
?>
```

Then in your file:

```
<?php 
  require_once(ROOT_PATH . '/check_fields.php');
  // more processing
?>
```